# Nesting styles for increased drawing speed

Tags: qgis, style, performance

I have zoning plans for a municipalities ( for example 5700 features in this one) and I have created a QGIS-style to make it look like the offical style.

There are 72 colours/patterns for the different zones (coarse version), and  at least twice the number of zones in a more detailed style. Some of the zoning codes share the same patterns/colours as other codes.

All the codes are four digit so I tried to regex the zoning-code and categorised them like shown on the image below.

Running this style on this number of features takes some time every time I do anything in QGIS.

So the question i: I was wondering if nesting the zone-styles would help with performance, or if this would just end up using more (simple check vs regex for the category -> sub-category)

[image: Symbology window screenshot]

Comment: Are the styles nested under 'naeringsbebyggelse' identical? If that's the case, you could combine these into one rule like `"KPAREALFOR" in ('1300', '1310', '1320', ...)`. I think this would be faster to render, although I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: All the styles under "Næringsbebyggelse" have the same style, yes. So you mean if should have one check with ORs and that might speed it up?